# How to get MimeMessage from IMessageSummary?

Tags: mailkit

I'm using MailKit to get a list of full IMessageSummaries like this:

```
var allMessages = remoteFolder.Fetch(remoteIndexList, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);
```

I'm not interested in any optimizations like downloading parts of the IMessageSummary etc., I just want the whole data, as fast as I can get it.

But using the above approach, I can't then read properly the HTML in the message's body, for example using `HtmlPreviewVisitor` because the `Body` property of `IMessageSummary` is a `BodyPartBasic`. I need the whole `MimeMessage`, obviously.

The problem is that if I want to get multiple `MimeMessages`, I can't, I can only get one at a time using `ImapClient.GetMessage(int index, ...)` method.

Is there a way to extract all of the parts from the original `MimeMessage` that was used to create `IMessageSummary` and use them with `HtmlPreviewVisitor` without having to download each full `MimeMessage` again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is:

```
foreach (var item in allMessages) {
    var message = remoteFolder.GetMessage (item.UniqueId);
}
```

The `IMessageSummary` doesn't actually contain the message or download the message, it just asks the IMAP server for various bits of metadata about the message (such as the structure of the message, the flags such as read/unread, the sender, subject, date, to, cc, reply-to, etc).

If you have no interest in fetching individual MIME parts from the IMAP server, then you might want to use a reduced set of `MessageSummaryItems` such as `MessageSummaryItems.All | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId` (I know, `All` seems like it should contain more than `Full`, but that's not how the IMAP aliases work...).

You may even be able to further reduce the `MessageSummaryItems` that you are requesting depending on what pieces of data you are planning to use.

For example, if you don't use the `IMessageSummaryItem.Envelope` property, then you don't need the `MessageSummaryItems.Envelope` flag and by not requesting it, you'll speed up the query because the IMAP server won't send you as much info.

Comment: Yes, I figured out I should use GetMessage() for each IMessageSummary but why isn't there GetMessages() method that would return a list of messages using just one request to the IMAP server, just like Fetch()?

Comment: Because that’s a lot of data that would be dumped into memory.

Comment: Thanks @jstedfast